# Component function binding not working from template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `delete-media` component:

```
@Component('Project', {
    selector: 'delete-media',
    templateUrl: '/AttachmentListComponent/deleteMedia.html',
    bindings: {
        onDelete: '&'
    }
})
@Inject('$mdDialog', 'MediaResourceProvider')
export class DeleteMediaComponent {

    public onDelete: Function;
    public deleteMedia():void {
        this.onDelete();
    }
}
```

In the template I have a button that calls the `onDelete` function:

```
<md-button class="md-primary md-confirm-button" ng-click="vm.deleteMedia()">
    delete
</md-button>
```

I load this `delete-media` component from my `attachmentListComponent`:

```
public deleteMediaAction(mediaItem: MediaModel): void {
    const templateType = this.mediaIsDeletable && !this.mediaIsDeleted ? 'delete-media' : 'show-deleted-media-information'
    const template = `<${templateType}
        media-item="${mediaItem}"
        on-delete="vm.deleteMedia()"
        ></${templateType}>`;

    this.$mdDialog
        .show({
            template,
            targetEvent: null,
            clickOutsideToClose: false
        })
}

public deleteMedia(){
    console.log('delete');
}
```

I want to call the `deleteMedia()` method in the `attachementListComponent` when I click the `delete` button in the `delete-media` component. But the way I'm doing it now doesn't work.

When I add the `delete-media` component directly into my `attachmentList.html` (which is the template of the `attachmentListComponent` like so:

```
<delete-media
    on-delete="vm.deleteMedia()">
</delete-media>
```

And I click the `delete` button in the `delete-media` component it does call the `deleteMedia()` method in the `attachmentListComponent`.

It looks like the `on-delete="vm.deleteMedia()"` binding doesn't work when I load the `delete-media` component directly in the `attachementListComponent`, but it does work when I load the component in the template of `attachementListComponent`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use bindings to pass back data to your parent from a mdDialog. You can use the .hide() and .then().

In my `<delete-media>` component I added `this.$mdDialog.hide();` to the `deleteMedia()` method. This hides the dialog. But it also gives a callback to the parent.

So in my `attachmentListComponent` I have:

```
this.$mdDialog
    .show({
        template,
        targetEvent: null,
        clickOutsideToClose: false
    })
    .then(() => {
        this.deleteMedia();
    });

public deleteMedia(){
    console.log('delete');
}
```

The `.then` gets called when the mdDialog is closed (hidden).